# Windows 8 + Ubuntu 13.10 + boot-repair stuck

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, boot-repair

I bought a laptop HP Envy Premium with Windows 8 on it. I wanted to install also Ubuntu 13.10 on it. 
I partitioned from windows the disk creating space for Linux. Then booting from a live ubuntu on a usb stick i installed on that space UBuntu. Now I at the boot only windows 8 is executed and grub does't appear. So I rebooted from live usb I installed boot-repair in order to run it. THe problem now is that boot repair gets stuck in the initial phase.
In particular in the phase when it's running os-prober. Here is some info maybe useful obtained running boot-repair with '-d' : http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6816377/ . 
Thanks in advance!

GP.

Comment: Assuming UEFI/Secure Boot, did you read [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/159545)?

Comment: Hi edwin! yes i did read that and it seems like it all sums up on disabling secure boot which i did. The problem for me is that boot-repair then gets stuck and i can't fix the boot process.

Comment: I am not sure about what this means but if I remove the usb stick while the live distro is already executed and I run boot-repair after it doesn't get stuck anymore and it allows me to apply the changes boot-repair suggests. The problem is now that this changes are not effective in particular i don't see grub at boot time but windows 8 boots instead.